# calling a variable from another function in python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that this has been asked before, but I cant for the life of me understand it. I'm trying to create a simple program that gets two dates, and counts shows how many days are left between them.

This is my current code:

```
month = 0
day = 0
year = 0

def getDate(): #gets the current date
    global month
    global day
    global year
    print( 'What is the current month?' )
    month = month + int(input())
    print( 'What is the current day?' )
    day = day + int(input())
    print( 'What is the current year?' )
    year = year + int(input())
    print( 'The current date is ' + str(month) + '/' + str(day) + '/' + str(year) + '. Is this correct?' )
    YESNO = input() #confirms date
    if YESNO == 'YES' or YESNO == 'yes':
        print( 'Okay.' )
    else:
        getDate()

    newMonth = 0
    newDay = 0
    newYear = 0

def newDate(): #gets the desired countdown date
    global newMonth
    global newDay
    global newYear

    print( 'What is the desired countdown month?' )
    newMonth = newMonth + int(input())
    print( 'What is the desired countdown day?' )
    newDay = newDay + int(input())
    print( 'What is the desired countdown year?' )
    newYear = newYear + int(input())
    print( 'The desired countdown date is ' + str(newMonth) + '/' + str(newDay) + '/' + str(newYear) + '. Is this correct?' )
    YESNO = input() #confirms date
    if YESNO == 'YES' or YESNO == 'yes':
        print( 'Okay.' )
    else:
        newDate()

def COUNTDOWN(): #prints countdown
    global newMonth
    global newDay
    global newYear

    global month
    global day
    global year

    if newMonth < Month:
        countDownMonth = int(Month) - int(newMonth)
    else:
        countDownMonth = int(newMonth) - int(Month)
    if newDay < Day:
        countDownDay = int(Day) - int(newDay)
    else:
        countDownDay = int(newDay) - int(Day)
    if newMonth < Year:
        countDownYear = int(Year) - int(newYear)
    else:
        countDownYear = int(newYear) - int(Year)
    print( countDownMonth + '/' + countDownDay + '/' + countDownYear )

getDate()
newDate()
COUNTDOWN()
```

EDIT:

I apologize, I didn't realize it wasn't indented.

EDIT:

My question is how do I create a cross-function variable?

Comment: In Python, indentation is very important. Ergo, could you please indent your code correctly?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. I have no idea what part of your problem you need help to understand.

Comment: why the below three lines is under getDate()?
`global newMonth
global newDay
global newYear`

Also if you are getting any error, please post  that traceback info.

Comment: i had read i needed that in order to modify global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The global keyword in python is used to rebind a global variable in a local context. That being said, it is generally good practice to avoid the usage of the global keyword whenever possible.

In the code that you posted, it is necessary to use global in the functions getDate and newDate in order to bind those names in the global environment. However, in COUNTDOWN, because you are not rebinding the names and are only accessing the values bound to those names, global is not necessary.

For more information look here: [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I just make your code workable as below:

```
month = 0
day = 0
year = 0
newMonth = 0
newDay = 0
newYear = 0

def getDate(): #gets the current date
    global month
    global day
    global year

    print( 'What is the current month?' )
    month = month + int(input())
    print( 'What is the current day?' )
    day = day + int(input())
    print( 'What is the current year?' )
    year = year + int(input())
    print( 'The current date is ' + str(month) + '/' + str(day) + '/' + str(year) + '. Is this correct?' )
    YESNO = raw_input() #confirms date
    print YESNO
    if YESNO == 'YES' or YESNO == 'yes':
        print( 'Okay.' )
    else:
        getDate()

def newDate(): #gets the desired countdown date
    global newMonth
    global newDay
    global newYear

    print( 'What is the desired countdown month?' )
    newMonth = newMonth + int(input())
    print( 'What is the desired countdown day?' )
    newDay = newDay + int(input())
    print( 'What is the desired countdown year?' )
    newYear = newYear + int(input())
    print( 'The desired countdown date is ' + str(newMonth) + '/' + str(newDay) + '/' + str(newYear) + '. Is this correct?' )
    YESNO = raw_input() #confirms date
    if YESNO == 'YES' or YESNO == 'yes':
        print( 'Okay.' )
    else:
        newDate()

def COUNTDOWN(): #prints countdown
    global newMonth
    global newDay
    global newYear
    global month
    global day
    global year

    if newMonth < month:
        countDownMonth = int(month) - int(newMonth)
    else:
        countDownMonth = int(newMonth) - int(month)
    if newDay < day:
        countDownDay = int(day) - int(newDay)
    else:
        countDownDay = int(newDay) - int(day)
    if newMonth < year:
        countDownYear = int(year) - int(newYear)
    else:
        countDownYear = int(newYear) - int(year)
    print( str(countDownMonth) + '/' + str(countDownDay) + '/' + str(countDownYear) )

getDate()
newDate()
COUNTDOWN()
```

In my env, this code is working, but  i am not sure whether the output correct or not.

Comment: okay, that works, few minor capitalization errors and the string string issue at the bottom of COUNTDOWN() in my source, but i would like to get away from global variables

Answer (score 0):

use the `global` keyword, like so:

```
def function():
    global variable
```

this basically says, I want to access variable, even though I know it is global I still want it anyway.

Only use this if you are Changing the variable, not just using whatever is inside it.
e.g.,

```
def example():
    global eg
    eg = 1
```

Here we use global because we are changing `eg`'s content. If we were to instead, USE `eg`'s content to do something different we would do this:

```
def example(eg):
    eg2 = eg
```

Here we are saying, 'I want to use the value that `eg` contains, but I dont want to change it'.
Then we have declared `eg2` to be the same as `eg`, but we have not changed `eg`

If you wanted to then use the outcome of the function example, you would add a 'return' line.

```
def example(eg):
    eg2 = eg
    return eg
```

then we would call the function like so:

```
eg3 = example(eg)
```

This puts the result of example into eg3.

Hope this helps :)